# How would I frankenstein-build a ~20-30lbs strength "helping hands"?

Tags: tools

I'd like a tool like a really large "helping hands", which is a soldering assistance tool with a couple of alligator clamps and lockable telescoping arms. I'd like several objects like that made of sturdier components, that can stay steady against around 15lbs-30lbs of force, and which I can use to mount things like my laptop, my phone, my keyboards, or misc other things. My primary use is moveable desk components, though.

What would yall suggest frankensteining together to build such a thing? My current thinking, which I'd like to improve on:

- I could use a monitor arm,
- attached to pieces of heavy furniture,
- then instead of mounting a monitor, mount a 5x5x2 piece of wood,
- and attach a clamp of some sort to the other side of that?

I found a build of something similar, but it's not as heavy duty as I'd like, since my target is for it to be pretty solid against my laptop + force from my hands: https://makezine.com/projects/heavy-duty-helping-hands/ - it's based on a household bendy light thing.

Here's the insufficient one for comparison: [image: insufficient helping hands idea]

another thing I could use might be a monitor arm, but I suspect that would be overkill in some ways and insufficient in others. example pic for comparison, this one is several hundred dollars - which might just be what my desired level of capability costs in raw hardware, I'm not sure yet: [image]

Comment: Please upload the image which does not show on the link provided.

Comment: The big deal with such a device will be the size or weight of the base.  Think about how heavy the base for a standard helping hands that is made to handle a PC board usually a few ounces and the base is quite large and heavy. I haven’t seen a store bought version but have used clue clamps and pipe to hold pieces almost exactly the same as helping hands on steroids but I had tacked the pipe to my steel work bench and when done I cut the weld but not every one has a 1000 lb welding table. C clamps to a wooden table may work.

Comment: Added images as requested by @r13. If I did it wrong feel free to let me know or edit! I want to make sure to stay within the rules so this doesn't get deleted, as figuring this out would make a significant difference to my life.

Comment: Sounds like you want an obscenely strong "gooseneck arm" but any I've found can do like 2 pounds maximum. You should evaluate whether you realistically need to attach a laptop to one of these arms...

Comment: re @EdBeal - the problem in my head is, what can the arm be made out of that will carry the weight sufficiently? I wouldn't have a problem mounting this to other furniture if there's a way to make or buy a telescoping arm at the level of capability I want.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'll edit to clarify what I'm thinking about a bit better. goosenecks are probably not strong enough in general, but something shaped more like a monitor arm maybe could do it?

Comment: Yes, monitor arms are purpose built to withstand quite a bit of leveraged force so if your requirement is to hold a laptop then it's not overkill but rather built-to-spec and will cost you several hundred dollars as you've noticed.

Comment: Cool, so that confirms that part of my thinking. Then the remaining question is how to mount things to the end of a monitor arm

Comment: I imagine a welder would be useful; either occupation or machine would be fine.

Comment: 1/2” pipe  is quite strong I have some metal blocks with holes drilled through   And a 1/4-20 bolt that is the set screw in each block at each of the 2 pipes per block. My clamps are held to the pipe with a bolt that was drilled through the pipe washers allow the clamp to be moved but tightened the screw and this setup with multiple clamps could hold 50+ lbs . But as I mentioned the base may need to be many times the size of whatever is being held in place my first attempt I welded C clamps directly to the pipe but needed more flexibility.

Comment: This question is both too broad and off topic here. It's not about home improvement and there's no clear question posed. VTC.

Comment: It's about how to build a thing for home workshop sort of use - is that not on topic here? if so, where should I go instead?

Comment: I think this question is on-topic. It's definitely in the spirit of "I am trying to solve problem XYZ. I have seen this solution but it's not strong enough. What can I use to make it better/right?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Staging poles/staging clamps come to mind. Look at theatrical/lighting suppliers.

"theatre staging clamps" gets you the clamps in most search engines. the clamps allow two poles to be rotated and slid with respect to each other, then locked in place. Freestanding light poles with bases either heavy, or to be screwed to the floor, can be had. You can also build entire 3-D structures with poles and staging clamps.

Comment: Oh awesome! Seems that things already come in parts there. That's great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a rectangular steel tube, with a hole in the middle to allow the flexible rods to get through, to handle heavier stuff. It can be connected to the main (vertical) support post through coupling or weld. This is just a rough idea, you need to develop and design the real thing though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about Chemistry stands?

https://www.banggood.com/60cm-Laboratory-Stands-Support-Lab-Clamp-Flask-Condenser-Stand-Cilp-Ring-Stand-Set-p-1108746.html
[image]
Or build the same sort of thing out of scaffold poles?

Comment: Your link produces a "404 - Not Found" message. This is precisely why link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: yeash, I messed up editing th url

Comment: This looks interesting! it doesn't look like it would quite handle the weight I had in mind as is, but a central pole base like this seems like it has a shot at being useful for some of the things I'd want this for. Thanks!